# Convert nested list in a string back to nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list stored in string format, that I want to convert it to python list

```
ll ='[["ABC",7,"A",9],["ABD",6,"B",8]]'
ll = list(ll)
print(ll)
```

My expected output

```
[["ABC",7,"A",9],["ABD",6,"B",8]]
```

Received output

```
['[', '[', '"', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"', ',', '7', ',', '"', 'A', '"', ',', '9', ']', ',', '[', '"', 'A', 'B', 'D', '"', ',', '6', ',', '"', 'B', '"', ',', '8', ']', ']']
```

please help

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display.

> **Note:** The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: **strings, bytes, numbers, tuples,
> lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None**.

```
import ast

ll='[["ABC",7,"A",9],["ABD",6,"B",8]]'    
ll = ast.literal_eval(ll)
```

**Output:**

```
[['ABC', 7, 'A', 9], ['ABD', 6, 'B', 8]]
```

Comment: Im going to take the first post claim here by 4.0 seconds xd

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json`.

```
import json
ll='[["ABC",7,"A",9],["ABD",6,"B",8]]'
ll = json.loads(ll)
print(ll)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation of Error:**

When you do `list(ll)`, python is expected to convert the given input tuple/set/iterator into list.

In your case, `ll` is a string which is internally a list of characters. So, when you apply `list(ll)`, Python is returning you a list of charecters.

**Recommendation**

As answered by @Zalak Bhalani, I would recommend `json.loads`.

```
import json

ll ='[["ABC",7,"A",9],["ABD",6,"B",8]]'
ll = json.loads(ll)
print(ll)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ast.literal_eval

```
import ast
x =ast.literal_eval('[["ABC",7,"A",9],["ABD",6,"B",8]]')
print(type(x))
print(x)
```

output

```
<class 'list'>
[['ABC', 7, 'A', 9], ['ABD', 6, 'B', 8]]
```